# Access Query Giving #Func! Error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have about 5,000 rows in a table that I need to parse the data from.  Sometimes the data was input like this

```
Jones No# 434
Jones
```

I am needing to strip out anything after the `NO#` and I have this query which works **IF** the row contains the text `NO#` but if it does not, I get a `#Func!` error.

What is the proper way in AC2013 to do this?

```
LastName: Left(LastName, InStr(LastName, "NO#")-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there's NO# in the string first using `IIF`.

`Instr` returns the position of the text, or 0 if it isn't in there - so just check that it's not 0.

`LastName: IIF(InStr(LastName, "NO#")<>0,Left(LastName, InStr(LastName, "NO#")-1),LastName)`

Comment: How could this be updated to if there is no space.  meaning the text is NO#434?

Comment: It will find NO# in either case - _Jones NO# 434_ and _Jones NO#434_ both have NO# at character 7 so will return just _Jones_

Comment: In my case it is not removing where there is no space.  Only where there is a space.

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't `InStr(LastName, "NO# ")` _< extra space after the #_?  I can't think of another reason why it would include the space.